# Images are disabled

Tags: bug, images

I can't see the pictures. I think they are disabled. What could be the reason?[image]

Comment: Are you getting any failed to load resource messages in Chrome's (or others) web console? Can you reach any other Gravatar images? http://en.gravatar.com/ has an example on their front page.

Comment: Yes there are some error messages in Firefox error console. No I cannot see the image on the front page of Gravatar site.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is an issue at StackExchange - all users I have spoken to have no issues with Gravatar images (they're pulled from gravatar.com not hosted on StackExchange).

The bigger issue is why your link to the imgur page (alluded to in your first screenshot) wasn't working. That image link is fine so leads me to believe it's possibly something at your end. If you're on an office PC have your employers blocked Gravatar and Imgur?

Can you check from a different PC, and also give it a day or so and recheck on your machine?

Nothing has been disabled from a StackExchange point of view.

Comment: This is my home PC

Comment: It works on the next day!!!

Answer (score 1):

I can see them fine over here. Probably your workplace is blocking them(if you are opening the site from your workplace).

A look at your web browser's JavaScript console (Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open it in Chrome) should show you the actual error.

Comment: This is my home PC